# Undefined index warning in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

```
if(isset($_POST['bul']))
{
    $marka1=$_POST['marka'];
    $model1=$_POST['model'];

   $que="SELECT * from  otomobil_tablosu WHERE markasi='$marka1' AND modeli='$model1'";
   $res=mysql_query($que);

  while($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)){

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['otomobilID'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";

  }
```

when I want to print the row of table there is undefined index warning... I could not find the problem

Comment: `$_POST['marka']` and `$_POST['model']`, also `$row['otomobilID']`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: In which line of code do you get this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific problem is that `mysql_fetch_row()` returns an **indexed array** and not an associative. You want `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

The more general problem is that you're using `mysql_*()` functions, and are highly vulnerable to SQL injection. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).